# RStudio Connect disconnects from server before app can load

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio-server, rsconnect

I am running an application that takes quite a while to load. I have to load up 7GB worth of data which when run locally takes the app about 220 seconds. However on my deployed app it disconnects from the server after roughly 120 seconds, before it can load.

I don't know exactly what I can put here since the Log doesn't show anything. If there is anywhere I can grab information from to show you all or if this is a known issue that can be easily solved I would love to know!

Comment: I don't think it very reasonable for you to load database sized files into your app. I would suggest putting the data into a database

Answer (score 1):

Are you using *shinyapps.io*? The free tier only allows you to use 1GB RAM. Loading 7GB data will definitely crash the server.

Comment: I am using RStudio Connect

Comment: If you are using RStudio Connect by default, it gives you 4 GB RAM. Increase this amount may be helpful, but I would agree with *@Pork Chop*, you may want to convert your file to a database, so you only query or load a small portion of it.